# Why is my Axios get call returning an old version of the file? Seems to be relying on browser cache

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a pretty basic function using axios. All it should do is get and log the value of a field in a JSON object hosted on a server. The code looks like this (with the URL replaced):

```
useEffect(() => {
    const configResponse = async () => {
    await axios.get(
        `{jsonfileaddress}`,
        
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.first_field);
    })}
      configResponse();
  }, []);
```

This code worked fine the first time I ran it. I realized I had made a typo in the file, re-uploaded it, but the function kept printing the old value. I'm positive that the file has been updated on the server. It even returns the new, correct value when I switch to incognito mode (Chrome) but it stops working when I switch back.

I have seen some answers involving custom headers and whatnot but these all end up returning a null or zero value when the axios call is made. Like I said, the function worked well but only once.